# Insert data into database using Fast api using python

Tags: python, arrays, oop, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and I'm working on inserting data into MY SQL database using the Fast API POST method. I have created a set of sample codes to create a schema and inserted the single data into the MY SQL table using the below sample code.

Ref link: https://codingnomads.co/blog/python-fastapi-tutorial

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, Session
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Float, String, Integer

app = FastAPI()

# SqlAlchemy Setup
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite+pysqlite:///./db.sqlite3:'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True, future=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
   db = SessionLocal()
   try:
      yield db
   finally:
      db.close()

# A SQLAlchemny ORM Place
class DBPlace(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'places'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
name = Column(String(50))
description = Column(String, nullable=True)
coffee = Column(Boolean)
wifi = Column(Boolean)
food = Column(Boolean)
lat = Column(Float)
lng = Column(Float)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# A Pydantic Place
class Place(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    coffee: bool
    wifi: bool
    food: bool
    lat: float
    lng: float

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# Methods for interacting with the database
def get_place(db: Session, place_id: int):
    return db.query(DBPlace).where(DBPlace.id == place_id).first()

def get_places(db: Session):
    return db.query(DBPlace).all()

def create_place(db: Session, place: Place):
    db_place = DBPlace(**place.dict())
    db.add(db_place)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_place)

    return db_place

# Routes for interacting with the API
@app.post('/places/', response_model=Place)
def create_places_view(place: Place, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_place = create_place(db, place)
    return db_place

@app.get('/places/', response_model=List[Place])
def get_places_view(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return get_places(db)

@app.get('/place/{place_id}')
def get_place_view(place_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return get_place(db, place_id)

@app.get('/')
async def root():
    return {'message': 'Hello World!'}
```

But I need to parse a list of arrays in the request to create_places_view and insert multiple values at once. so how to achieve this in Fast API. Any pointers/help? Thanks

Example:

> ```
>     [{name: str
>     description: Optional[str] = None
>     coffee: bool
>     wifi: bool
>     food: bool
>     lat: float
>     lng: float }, 
>     {name: str
>     description: Optional[str] = None
>     coffee: bool
>     wifi: bool
>     food: bool
>     lat: float
>     lng: float }]
> ```

Comment: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite+pysqlite:///./db.sqlite3:'` - this does not seem like MySQL. But to define a list of objects in FastAPI, use `from typing import List`, then `create_places_view(places: List[Place], ...)`. `places` will then be a list you can create SQLAlchemy objects from and insert into the database.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh, But I have created a loop and appended the values to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looped the value to create user. While sending the post request in the list of dict.

```
# Fast API to create/insert a new user
@app.post('/create_place_view/', responses={404: {"model": Message}})
async def create_place(user: List[Place], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if not user:
          return JSONResponse(status_code=404, content={"message": "Place details not found"})
    else:
         places_list = []
         for places in place:
             db_place = create_places(db, places)
             place_json = places.dict()
             places_list.append(places_json)
    return JSONResponse(content=places_list)
```